# PHP Login System Code Edit

Tags: php, html, authentication, web

I have implemented this login system on my website: http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/cool-login-system-php-jquery/

I am new to `php` so my question is, when a user registers with a username and email address, how can display that username that choose in the email. Right now `im` only sending them their password.

Also, how can I check that when a user tries to sign up for an account, that email address they put in is not already used up for an account? Right now when you sign up for an account that already has a account before, the system just assigns that email address a new password and the old password doesn't work.

```
<?php

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';
// Those two files can be included only if INCLUDE_CHECK is defined


session_name('tzLogin');
// Starting the session

session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
// Making the cookie live for 2 weeks

session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['tzRemember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
{
    // If you are logged in, but you don't have the tzRemember cookie (browser restart)
    // and you have not checked the rememberMe checkbox:

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    // Destroy the session
}


if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: DownloadLinks.php");
    exit;
}

if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{
    // Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

    $err = array();
    // Will hold our errors


    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Escaping all input data

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {
            // If everything is OK login

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

            // Store some data in the session

            setcookie('tzRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
        }
        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if($err)
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    // Save the error messages in the session

    header("Location: DownloadLinks.php");
    exit;
}
else if($_POST['submit']=='Register')
{
    // If the Register form has been submitted

    $err = array();

    if(strlen($_POST['username'])<4 || strlen($_POST['username'])>32)
    {
        $err[]='Your username must be between 3 and 32 characters!';
    }

    if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9\-\_\.]+/i',$_POST['username']))
    {
        $err[]='Your username contains invalid characters!';
    }

    if(!checkEmail($_POST['email']))
    {
        $err[]='Your email is not valid!';
    }

    if(!count($err))
    {
        // If there are no errors

        $pass = substr(md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].microtime().rand(1,100000)),0,6);
        // Generate a random password

        $_POST['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        // Escape the input data


        mysql_query("   INSERT INTO tz_members(usr,pass,email,regIP,dt)
                        VALUES(

                            '".$_POST['username']."',
                            '".md5($pass)."',
                            '".$_POST['email']."',
                            '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                            NOW()

                        )");

        if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
        {

         require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "Mail <mail@mail.com>";
 $to = $_POST['email'];
 $subject = "Registration System- Your New Password";


 $body = "Thank you for registering \n You username is: $usr $_SESSION[usr]
 Your password is: $pass \n Please login with your registered email and password";

 $host = "mail.host.com";
 $username = "username";
 $password = "password";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   $_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']='We sent you an email with your new password! Check your junk/spam too!';}

        }

        else $err[]='This username is already taken!';
    }

    if(count($err))
    {
        $_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    }   

    header("Location: DownloadLinks.php");
    exit;
}

$script = '';

if($_SESSION['msg'])
{
    // The script below shows the sliding panel on page load

    $script = '
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){

            $("div#panel").show();
            $("#toggle a").toggle();
        });

    </script>';

}
?>
```

Comment: Just query the database for their email address. If it is in there already, they already have an account.

Comment: bad tutorial, do not use

Comment: sorry im just a beginner, why is this code bad? im just using it on a website to restrict access to a page, thats all so people have to register.

Comment: Normally no one should give you an answer cause you do not accept correct answers. This community is based on the "gave and take" principle. You just take but do not give anything. If you do that in your real life, you most likely do not have your friends for a long time. Think about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At registeration you did not set `$_SESSION['usr]`. Instead use `$_POST['username']`.

```
 $body = "Thank you for registering at The Quran Reciters Members Page \n You username is: " . $_POST['username'] . "
 Your password is: $pass \n Please login with your registered email and password";
```

In order to make sure the user is not a registered user, you should first query the database for the username and email address.  The same way you do the login:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr='" . $_POST['username'] . "' AND email = '" . $_POST['email']  ."'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {
            // return an error message and display the registration form again
        }
```

But as Dagon mention, this is not a very good tutorial. I hope this is only for learning and not a system used for production.

Comment: thank you so much, the first part worked. if i just did this
You username is: $_POST['username'] , it caused a syntax error but when i did this 
$username = $_POST['username']; and then You username is: $username , it worked

Comment: I didn't get the second part, can you please show me where to put that code?

is it here: 

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {

Comment: Before you insert the new registration to the databse, check if the username is available and the email address is not already in your db. Alternatively set your database so the username and email address are unique.